# it's possible to obtain the lagrange multipliers from an optimal solution in Pyomo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyomo, glpk

I'd like to know how it's possible to obtain the lagrange multipliers from an optimal solution in a Concrete model solved with glpk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in `gurobi`, try it out and tell me if it works with `glpk`.

You need to prompt getting the Lagrange multipliers / dual variable in pyomo by putting the following line somewhere before solving your model:

```
model.dual = Suffix(direction=Suffix.IMPORT)
```

And then after solving the model, you can get the dual variable for all your constraints by:

```
model.dual.pprint()
```